# org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [org.apache.qpid.jms.message.JmsMessage] to [java.lang.String]

Tags: java, spring-boot, queue, azureservicebus

```
    Reading message from Azure service bus:
    org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [org.apache.qpid.jms.message.JmsMessage] to [java.lang.String] for org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage@39945b52, failedMessage=org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage@39945b52
    
    java code:
```

import org.apache.qpid.jms.message.JmsMessage;

@Component
Public class AzureserviceBusListner {
private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "teste01";

@JmsListener(destination = QUEUE_NAME,containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")

```
    public void receive(String msg) {

      System.out.println("Azure received message:::: "+msg);    

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a JmsTextMessage iinstead of a JmsMessage:

```
        //Autowire a JmsTemplate first, and then

        jmsTemplate.send("<your-destination-name>", new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            TextMessagemessage = session.createTextMessage("message payload");

            return message;
        }
    });
```

I am curious of what's is the need here to send a JmsMessage instead of sub class? I think you can also use message converter to convert the JmsMessage to sub classes as you need when sending/receiving messages.

Besides, do you use the azure-spring-boot-starter-servicebus-jms
If so, converting JmsMessage to other JAVA type in message converter will not work because that library doesn't support customize messageconverter for JmsListener.